# How can I stop my server being an "open DNS resolver"?

Tags: networking, server, security, dns

This morning I got a letter from my ISP saying that my Ubuntu Server (13.10) can be used as an "open DNS resolver". They propose 3 possible solutions to fix this problem:

1. Limit access to recursive servers
2. Authorisation servers are not
   allowed to implement recursion
3. The access to your server could be
   limited by using a firewall

So I did some research and found out (through http://www.openresolver.jp/en/) that my server is indeed vulnerable. The problem however is, that according to my whereabouts, I never installed an DNS server on the machine.

After reading a bit more, I found out that DNSMasq is installed by default and people suggest securing it, but I can't find any config file whatsoever. When I run `ps aux | grep dnsmasq`, I do get:

```
server   21966  0.0  0.0   8172   952 pts/1    S+   09:09   0:00 grep --color=auto dnsmasq
```

<strike>Also, I have a feeling my OpenVPN service could have something to do with it.</strike> My server is still vulnerable even after I disable my OpenVPN service.

I would be thankful to anyone who has any tip(s) or advice on how to make my server safe and shut down or secure the responsible service. If I don't manage to solve the issue, my ISP will disconnect me from the network.

Comment: Can you stop the OpenVPN service and rerun the openresolver check?

Comment: @Jos, Just stopped the OpenVPN service and the server is still vulnerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by unchecking an option that was turned on by default on my router. After I disabled the "Enable DNS Relay" option, I passed the test at http://openresolver.com/.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any service for other user from internet on your server simple `sudo ufw enable`. Status of fw you can see with `sudo ufw status`. This will turn you firewall app with default deny all policy for inbound traffic. This will also prevent "Open DNS resolver" to talk with internet without control

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just turned on the firewall using ``sudo ufw enable`` but http://openresolver.com/ indicates that the server is still vulnerable.

Comment: Something is wrong. How openresolver.com can test your ip if ufw is enabled and do not accept connection? Test from site not from terminal because when you test from terminal you initate connection and will pass through fw. Also when you do testing you can watch log of ufw with `tail -f /var/log/ufw.log`. If connection is blocked you will see.

Comment: I did test it from the website by filling out the IP-address in the form on the bottom of the page. I checked the logs and nothing comes up. Also, I noticed that after enabling the firewall, my web server went down too on that domain. Could have anything to do with the router perhaps? Thanks again.

Comment: If topology is `server [private ip]` -> `router lan port [private ip]` -> `nat on router` -> `wan router port [public ip]` -> `internet` you are scan public ip, router ip, not server. Probably on router you have port 80 fw for web server. In this scenario stop ufw with `sudo ufw disable` and you web servis will be up. If you can give me more detail about topology of you network and service if you wish to solve problem.

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward setup. There's a router to which the server is connected through LAN with a static IP. The server has the following network interfaces, configured for OpenVPN I believe: ``auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports em1``

Comment: Ok. Your router do NAT for local network. Look port fw rules. Bring up firewall on router and allow only needed port's.

Comment: The problem was the "Enable DNS Relay" option in my router (see my answer). Thanks a lot for helping out!